# Cant achieve to finish the role reaction bot on discord js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a role reaction bot, Something very easy just send a message and give a role if someone react to. I've kind of tried everything and I don't see the error, I'm kind of new in this I started yesterday.
I'm using discord V12 cause there is more information online about it.
Note: There is some parts of code that are not here (tokens, etc)

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.channel.id === '876098680992723007')
        if (message.author.bot) return false;
    
        const Role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("876163491118084156");
        const Filter = (reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id;
        const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`React to get the member role`)
        const reactionMessage = await message.channel.send(Embed);

        await reactionMessage.react("");
        reactionMessage.awaitReactions(Filter, {max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"]}).then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            message.member.roles.add(Role1)

         });
});
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors at all?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using raw JSON, it's much easier to manipulate posts with reactions.
In a few lines the command can do many posts by reactions.

```js
var infos = {
  "react1": {
    "emoji1": "",
    "emoji2": "",
    "channel": "844787535333949501",
    "role1": "844416225630748702",
    "role2": "844416390668484609",
    "message": "844787829091336204"
  },
  "react2": {
    "emoji1": "",
    "emoji2": "",
    "channel": "844787535333949501",
    "role1": "844414135202611221",
    "role2": "844416103173455882",
    "message": "844789255133724692"
  }
}
```

this only works with discord emojis, and all the information key and value, key is the type and value is the id referring to the type.

```js
client.on('raw', async (p) => {
    if(!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(p.t)) return;
    // Collecting only additions and removals from reactions

    var slots = Object.entries(infos).map(([a, b]) => a)
    slots.filter(async (names) => {
        //filtering by reaction role numbers
        var result = Object.entries(infos[names]).map(([a, b]) => (a.includes('emoji')) ? a : undefined).filter((x) => x !== undefined)
        // Collecting all definite emojis in one reaction role
        result.forEach((x, i) => {
            var emoji = infos[names]["emoji"+(i+1)];
            var role = infos[names]["role"+(i+1)];
            // As the number of positions and number of emojis are the same, you don't need to filter the positions just use the same emoji index
            var channel = infos[names]["channel"];
            var mensagem = infos[names]["message"];

            // If the information is not the same, it cancels
            if (p.d.emoji.name !== emoji) return;  
            if (p.d.channel_id != channel) return;
            if (p.d.message_id != message) return;

            var guild = client.guilds.cache.get(p.d.guild_id)
            var member = guild.members.cache.get(p.d.user_id)
  
            if (member.user.bot)
                return;
            if (p.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD")
                member.roles.add(role)
            if (p.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE")
                member.roles.remove(role)
        });
    });
});
```